# Save a website with PhantomJS like ctrl+s in my browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, nginx, phantomjs

I'm trying to save a site which I later on want to use it on Nginx.

I can successfully **page.render** to create an image of the site, and it looks good, but I don't need content this way.

**I tried doing fs.write("index.html", page.content, 'w')**

Which generated an almost good HTML file with images, but it looks really off, I believe the problem is, it depends on javascripts, css and other files. (and it also gives a lot of 404 on files)

If I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> the site using **chrome**, and upload all the files to Nginx, it works exactly the way I need.
But I need this to happen automatically periodically, so I want to use PhantomJS (or an alternative if it isn't possible on PhantomJS)

As a side note, I tried `wget -m URL` and it didn't work either.

here is the PhantonJS-Script that works for screenshot:

```
function capture(sizes, callback) {
  var page = require('webpage').create();
  page.viewportSize = {width: sizes[0], height: height};
  //page.zoomFactor = 1;
  page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
      console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    } else {
      page.scrollPosition = {
        top: 100,
        left: 0
      };
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Generating:" + sizes[0]);
        var filename = output + "_" + sizes[0];
        page.render(filename + '.jpeg', {format: 'jpeg', quality: qual});
        page.close();
        callback.apply();
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS isn't really the best tool here, because you'd anyway need to fix paths to downloaded css, js, image files in html (which Chrome does when saving a page).

I suggest this wget usage:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -nd -o log.txt http://example.com/page/
```

This will download the target page with its resource files and save them into the current directory, rewriting html so that it's correctly linked to those files.

Comment: It didn't work.
problem is that the site is dynamically generated by javascripts. also it seems like I have to scroll down too to get extra content. (in phantomJS I did a page.scrollposition, top =100; and let the site compute for 5 seconds)
Also there's conflicts with .js scripts

Comment: Please, extend your question, showing minimal working PhantomJS code example.